# 2D vector segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stdvector

The following code is giving me a segmentation fault and I don't understand the problem. I think there's some mistake in the way I've used vectors but I don't know what that is. Please help.

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<sstream>  
#include<vector>  
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;  

int main()  
{
    int T;
    vector<int>n,m;
    vector<vector<int> >arr;
    int temp;
    cin>>T;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++) 
    {
        cin>>temp;
        n.push_back(temp);
        cin>>temp;
        m.push_back(temp);
        vector<int>temp_vec(temp);
        for(int j=0;j<temp;j++)
        {
            int temp2;
            cin>>temp2;
            temp_vec[j]=(temp2);
        }
        sort(temp_vec.begin(),temp_vec.end());
        arr.push_back(temp_vec);
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What's the specific input for which you're getting an error?

Comment: @atru I had allocated some memory to temp_vec by this: vector<int>temp_vec(temp); I think it should work like this

Comment: OK, true. I didn't check properly. Still, add a description and sample input so  we can readily reproduce your problem.

Comment: actually this is a small part of the program I made while solving a problem on codechef.. When I'm submitting,  I'm getting segmentation fault..I dont know about the sample input.. this portion of my program is what looks to me to be problematic

Comment: Could you please add to the question what is the problem that the posted code is supposed to solve? What are you trying to do?

Comment: www.codechef.com/problems/CLEANUP

Answer (score -2):

When you declare a vector of any type it does not have any elements until you initialize and put the value into it. Your code:

```
arr.push_back(temp_vec);
```

is trying to insert `temp_vec` into a non-existent vector inside the vector `arr` at position **0**.

You should know the size of the vector that you want to use and then initialize that with the size of the constructor:

```
vector<vector<int> >arr(size);
```

for example:

```
vector<vector<int> >arr(64);
```

This will be initialize the vector `arr` with 64 or x empty elements.

Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494069/2d-vector-giving-segmentation-fault)

Comment: In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140953/segmentation-fault-on-two-dimensional-vector

Comment: can you explain why the same thing is not required

Comment: @VishalSharma I added the link for the other answers in the question. Probably could help.

Comment: In the link I've given,  the 2-d vector C  has not been given any size? Why does it work there?